# Redimension image on android

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap

I have a function that resize the image in function of the ideal proportion between the height and width for my app the problem is the quality of the image when i try to resize the image it lose a lot of quality it get pixeled like if you resize it on paint, there is any way to improve the quality?

perfect image ratio 0,744   (320x430)
there is my code

```
public Bitmap redimensionarImagenMaximo(Bitmap mBitmap, float newWidth, float newHeigth){
       //Redimensionamos
       int width = mBitmap.getWidth();
       int height = mBitmap.getHeight();
       float actual = (float)width/height;
       double perfect = 0.7441;
       float scaleWidth;
       float scaleHeight;
       if(perfect >= actual)
       {
           scaleHeight = ((float) newHeigth) / height;
           scaleWidth = scaleHeight;

       }
       else if(perfect <= actual)
       {
           scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
           scaleHeight = scaleWidth;
       }
       else 
       {
           scaleWidth = newWidth;
           scaleHeight = newHeigth;
       }
       // create a matrix for the manipulation
       Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
       // resize the bit map
       matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
       // recreate the new Bitmap
       return Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
    }
```

Comment: What's the bitmap size? What's the target size?

Comment: thanks for the reply the perfect image is 320x430 the original size change in fuction of the differents images that people can up to my app

Answer (score 0):

How about replacing the last line of code:

```
return Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);
```

Set the last parameter to `true` for bilinear interpolation.

Or you can simply use

```
return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBitmap, width, height, true);
```

Comment: If i just change filter to true, nothing changes it the same size/quality and i use the second one the size increase so much and i want a low size (there are jpg with 50kbs and have better quality )

Comment: The first line will do bilinear interpolation for down scaling, but nearest neighborhood for up scaling. Are you trying to up scale an image so that the quality is poor?

Comment: I am trying to resized the image to a 320x430(it can have a margin) so i can show the picture in the phone without distorsion and i want to reduce the size of the image too but that quality is so poor